# Jquery Dropshadow on relative (height 80%) div element?

Tags: jquery, drop-shadow

anybody knows if there is any form of autoReinitialise on jquery.dropshadow.js? I created a div with 80% height, and the shadow is nice. However whenever you resize the page and hence the div resizes too, the shadow keeps it's old height. The position changes whatsoever.

Many thanks,

Mike

Comment: Now i noticed that this also effects jquery.jscrollable.js. I am using both (a scrollbar and a shadow) on an absolute positioned div where height has a percentage value. Any hint is very appreciated.